# Binding Data to Word 2007 Content Controls Using Visual Studio Tools for the Office System (3.0)

Tags: ms-word, openxml

I found this article - [Binding Data to Word 2007 Content Controls Using Visual Studio Tools for the Office System (3.0)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb967663.aspx) - and thought that that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I want to programatically build a product brochure using Content Controls and Open XML.

The article in question refers to an accompanying video which unfortunately does not appear to be available, nor does the code.

I posted a comment to ask where they are but in the meantime does anybody know of a good example. There are plenty of examples of binding/merging one record into an Open XML Word document. But I want to bind a whole list of records to create a product brochure.

Can anyone point me to good tutorial?

Comment: does the below answer your question? if not, can you post more code/details and I'll try to provide a more detailed analysis.

Comment: @Otaku, thanks. In the end I went down a different route. But the article you point out is exactly what I was looking for. I may now refactor and go down the Word Control Toolkit route after all. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably one of the better articles I've seen on this from Eric White: [Creating Data-Bound Content Controls using the Open XML SDK and LINQ to XML](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2008/10/19/creating-data-bound-content-controls-using-the-open-xml-sdk-and-linq-to-xml.aspx).

Also, to get familiar with how Content Controls work in WordprocessingML you may want to toy around with the open-source [Word Content Control Toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=dbe).

For a repeater type of scenario to bring in mulitple data pieces, there is a product catalog example for how to do this in PowerPoint at [Adding Repeating Data to PowerPoint](http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_jones/archive/2009/08/13/adding-repeating-data-to-powerpoint.aspx). The concepts can be ported over to Word and Content Controls. (This original one was done with tables ported to Word at [Pushing Data from a Database into a Word Document](http://blogs.msdn.com/brian_jones/archive/2009/01/19/pushing-data-from-a-database-into-a-word-document.aspx))

Comment: Thanks Otaku, I'm already aware of Eric's articles and I've already used the content controls toolkit. But only to deal with one record. As I said in my question I want to know how to push multiple records into a document to create a brochure of products. I can't use word automation - my app is web app.

Comment: @Simon Lomax: I've updated the text a bit. There is an example of how to do this in PowerPoint, see link above. It sounds like you're pretty familiar with Content Controls, so this should be an easy-enough port to WordprocessingML.